# Same fields in different Embedded

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I have 3 tables A, B, C:

```
@Embeddable
public class AModel {
    @Column(name = "a_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "a_name")
    private String name;
}

@Embeddable
public class BModel {
    @Column(name = "b_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    private int aId;
    @Column(name = "b_name")
    private String name;
}

@Embeddable
public class CModel {
    @Column(name = "c_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    private int aId;
    @Column(name = "c_name")
    private String name;
}
```

and I have immutable entity

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class AEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "a_id")
    private int id;

    @Embedded
    private AModel aModel;
    @Embedded
    private BModel bModel;
    @Embedded
    private CModel cModel;
}
```

which I create with EntityManager.createNativeQuery and following query:

```
select * from A natural join B natural join C;
```

But I got an exception caused by:

```
org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:  Table [aentity] contains physical column name [a_id] represented by different logical column names: [a_id], [aId]
```

Upd: **Solution**

Adding following annotation to bModel and cModel can solve this problem:

```
@AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "aId", column = @Column(name = "a_id", insertable = false, updatable = false))
    })
```

Comment: check whether `hibernate.cfg.xml` file also contains mapping for this class?

Comment: @Imran, I am not using hibernate.cfg.xml, it can be in Spring Boot with AutoConfiguration, but the problem is, BModel has a_id and CModel has a_id, so I want to ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using @Id,@Column with your embeddable class AModel. If you want to make AModel as your composite key then you can use @EmbeddedId. The issue is coming as you are defining @Column(name = a_id) inside AEntity and also the same thing inside embeddable class AModel so getting duplicate logical mapping.

Comment: I made a mistake, but I meant a_id field in AModel, BModel, CModel and single int filed a_id in AEntity. Source code was corrected.

Comment: Ok got it. Since you can have a single column with a_id name,then you can use @AttributeOverrides annotation . Check this link for its use https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html